# How can I use a seperator for group concat?

Tags: mysql, group-concat

```
 $pdo = $db->query('SELECT *, GROUP_CONCAT(friends.name, "<br>") AS result FROM animals  LEFT JOIN friends ON animals.id=friends.id');
```

The result:

```
anna
,fred
```

The result that I wish to have:

```
anna
fred
```

Comment: It seems already correct, you might have a ",fred" in your data.

Comment: I can never understad why you'd want to use GROUP_CONCAT (or CONCAT) in conjunction with a PHP parsed query.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just need to specify the `SEPARATOR` in the `GROUP_CONCAT`

```
$pdo = $db->query('SELECT *, GROUP_CONCAT(friends.name SEPARATOR "<br>") AS result FROM animals  LEFT JOIN friends ON animals.id=friends.id');
```

Further details and explanation [here](http://www.w3resource.com/mysql/aggregate-functions-and-grouping/aggregate-functions-and-grouping-group_concat.php#CP3)